# i have generated 4 random values. how do i write them into a text file in its first line separated only by a semicolon using scilab?

Tags: scilab

I have generated the random values using rand function as below.

```
    h=0
    g=-120
    r1 = (h-g)*rand()+g;
    r2 = (h-g)*rand()+g;
    r3 = (h-g)*rand()+g;
    r4 = (h-g)*rand()+g;
```

how do I copy those values into a text file in this format "37; 40; 56; 28"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify your own separator when using [`csvwrite`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/csvWrite.html).

```
h=0
g=-120
M = (h-g)*rand(1,4)+g;
csvWrite(M, "my_file.csv", ";");
```